# Not able to find directory using File Class in Windows

Tags: java, android, windows

I am working on Android Project. I want to write output inside my local repository.So, i am using File Class.i am using Windows.This is my code:

```
String fileName = "C:\\LocationAPI";
File f1 = new File(fileName);

if(f1.isDirectory()){
Log.d("write","Is a Directory")
}
else{
Log.d("write","Not a Directory");
  }
```

Result is : Not a Directory.
LocationAPI directory exists inside C drive.
Can somebody tell me the mistake i did?

Comment: What does `f1.exists()` say?

Comment: You cant access hard drive directly even if you are running the code in Emulator. You need a webservice for this. However the above will work with Java Application surely, but not with Android

Comment: @kedarnath I think You are right . i am not able to use this class in Android Environment. Do you know some class compatible with Android to write a file inside Android Project

Comment: @saladinxu this is a method to check whether this file exists or not

Comment: @Yati , See if your goal is to simply write some content into file then there is File API in Android, But if you want to write file on C:\ or D:\ then you need to get help of a webservice. Only webservice can do this.

Comment: @Kedarnath Your suggestion is very helpful.Thanks.I am testing my app in the Android emulator. According to File API of android, there is some way to write file on local machine..I am looking forward to see this.

Comment: @Yati, You welcome. This link should help you. [Data Storage in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: @Yati just want to inform you, "local machine" is the device's local storage. Even if you're running emulator on PC, "local machine" is still the emulator's local storage, not PC's hard drive.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks man.I want to generate text file from my code.Is it possible to open that file from emulator local storage to my Local machine..

Comment: @Yati if you want to do it manually, the it's possible to "pull" the file from emulator's to your PC. Go to DDMS, and open "File Explorer" tab (if not shown, from menu, Window-Show View-File Explorer). Browse to your file and click the disk button.

Comment: Finally i Find the solution.I am able to write .txt file inside sdcard of device. I designed one method to return file:
   public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
         // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
         File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/files", albumName);
        Log.d("File", "Bug file Created" + file.getAbsolutePath());
         return file;
     }

Comment: To write inside this file:

     StringBuffer report = formatReport(data);
    String filename = "bugReport.txt";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    
    try{
     outputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.getAlbumStorageDir(filename));
     outputStream.write(report.toString().getBytes());
     Log.d("File","Report Generated");
     outputStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Thank you guys for your support